# angular ui tab is not listening to select Deselect is not deselecting new tab while checking for Dirty flag

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-tabset

I have to implement Dirty checking while scrolling  through different tabs.
But when I am trying to implement this select() and deselect() method of angular ui tab is not listening and stopping navigation to another tab.

I am explicitly making them active but still no luck.

Could you please help me to debug this issue or provide me workaround for that ?

Dashboard.html

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
    <!--  <uib-tab heading="Dashboard" index="0">
        <ng-include src="'/project/Dashboard.html'">
        </ng-include>
     </uib-tab> -->
    <uib-tab  index="$index" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" 
    deselect="switchTabs(tab)" select="selectTab(tab)" disable="tab.disabled">
    <uib-tab-heading>
           {{tab.title}} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="removeTab($index)" ng-hide="tab.tabId===-1"></i> 
     </uib-tab-heading>
      <ng-include src="tab.templateUrl">
      </ng-include>
    </uib-tab>
 </uib-tabset>
```

DashboardCtrl.js

```
$scope.tabs = [];
$scope.activeTab = 0;
$scope.selectTab = function(tabInfo) {


console.log("tab Info"+tabInfo.title);

if($scope.activeTab > 0)
{
$scope.tabs[$scope.activeTab].active=true;
$scope.active = $scope.activeTab;
}

};


$scope.switchTabs = function(tabInfo) {
$scope.prevActiveTab = tabInfo.tabId;
var tabNumbers = $scope.tabs.length;
var tabActivateId = -1;
for(var i=0; i<tabNumbers; i++)
{
if($scope.tabs[i].tabId === tabInfo.tabId)
{
tabActivateId = i;
}

}

if(tabActivateId>=0)
{
$scope.tabs[tabActivateId].active=true;
$scope.active = tabActivateId;
$scope.activeTab = tabActivateId;
}


if($scope.isViewDirty === true)
{
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
openConfirmationModal('sm');


}
else
{
$scope.isViewDirty = false;
}



};
```

This is not listening any event nor selecting active tab correctly.

Angular JS Version 1.4.3
Bootstrap Version 0.14.3

---